# Engineering Change Order Forms

Tags: forms

What have others used when a customer wants a particular feature and they have required a signed document detailing the feature and expectations for that feature? Are there any 'engineering change forms' available to use?

We are going to move towards this with our customers to reduce confusion and meet the customer's overall expectation during the requirements process. Email communication is too disjointed and has led to miscommunication during delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to just make it up as you go along.  As you allude to, anything on paper is going to be better than what you have with email now.

As long as you include a description of the feature, the impact it will have on the schedule, a date, and a dotted line to sign on then that should be enough information.

In fact making it too long and involved will make you wish for the simplicity of just a plain email trail ;-)